# How to get indicator values and previous candle's open/close values into variables from higher&lower time frames for alert conditions

Tags: pine-script

I have two alert conditions. I have them in my indicator, I apply the alerts on the 15 minute time frame. That is my main time frame. I want to receive alert immediately when all the conditions happen to be met at the same time. Some conditions refer to higher and lower time frames compared to my main 15 minute time frame. I don't know how to get specific current values of higher and lower time frames.

My alert conditions:

```
Long = oneHourTenSma > oneHourTwentySma and fiveMinuteRsi < 50 and ( (oneHourPreviousClose < oneHourPreviousOpen) or (oneHourPreviousPreviousClose < oneHourPreviousPreviousOpen and oneHourPreviousClose > oneHourPreviousOpen) )
```

and

```
Short = fourHourTenSma < fourHourTwentySma and fiveMinuteRsi < 50 and ( (oneHourPreviousClose > oneHourPreviousOpen) or (oneHourPreviousPreviousClose > oneHourPreviousPreviousOpen and oneHourPreviousClose < oneHourPreviousOpen) )
```

How to get the 5 minute time frame's RSI value into my variable 'fiveMinuteRsi' (lower time frame)?

From the 1 hour time frame (higher time frame) how to get the previous candle's close value into my variable 'oneHourPreviousClose'?

From the 1 hour time frame (higher time frame) how to get the close value of the candle that is before the previous candle into my variable 'oneHourPreviousPreviousClose'?

From the 1 hour time frame (higher time frame) how to get the previous candle's open value into my variable 'oneHourPreviousOpen'?

From the 1 hour time frame (higher time frame) how to get the open value of the candle that is before the previous candle into my variable 'oneHourPreviousPreviousOpen'?

I am asking for the exact code solutions. I know it has to do with the request.security and the request.security_lower_tf function, I tried using them but I don't know how to do it properly so please anyone can provide solutions for these 5 easy questions?

(The other variables that I'm not asking about like the 'oneHourTenSma' are already done thanks to a kind forum member. This was the solution:

```
f_secureSecurity(_symbol, _res, _src) =>
    request.security(_symbol, _res, _src[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on))
```

Comment: Could you use the open and close values and (assuming you're on the 15 minute time frame) use every 4th or 8th element? i.e `oneHourPreviousClose = close[3], oneHourPreviousPreviousClose[7]`?